# How can Isaiah 11:11 be fulfilled if many of the nations mentioned no longer have significant Jewish population?

Tags: messiah, navi-prophets, isaiah-yeshaya-the-book

Isaiah 11:11

יא  וְהָיָה בַּיּוֹם הַהוּא, יוֹסִיף אֲדֹנָי שֵׁנִית יָדוֹ, לִקְנוֹת, אֶת-שְׁאָר עַמּוֹ--אֲשֶׁר יִשָּׁאֵר מֵאַשּׁוּר וּמִמִּצְרַיִם וּמִפַּתְרוֹס וּמִכּוּשׁ, וּמֵעֵילָם וּמִשִּׁנְעָר וּמֵחֲמָת, וּמֵאִיֵּי, הַיָּם.

Says that God will once again extend his hand to gather the remnant a second time in Assyria which was in modern Iraq, Egypt, Pathros which was in modern Egypt, Cush which was in modern Sudan, Elam which is in modern Iran, and Shinar and Hamath which is in modern Syria in the days of the Messiah. However, many Jews of those lands no longer live in those lands.

Jewish Population in those lands:

Assyria(modern Iraq)  <10

Egypt and Pathros(modern Iraq)  6-10

Cush(Sudan)  0

Elam(Iran)  8,756-25,000

Shinar and Hamath(modern Syria)  0

So my question is: 
How exactly is that prophesy in Isaiah 11:11 that God gave Isaiah going to be fulfilled in the time of the Messiah if some of these lands have absolutely no more Jews?

Answer (score 1):

You're asking this question with the mindset that we aren't already in the Messianic Age. The Messianic Age relates to the idea that the world is changing in such a way that we are ready to accept the Mashiach once he has arrived. It isn't simply an age marked by "He's not here/He's here."

***In fact, every generation is believed to have an individual who meets all of the characteristics of being the Mashiach. The revelation hasn't occurred yet because the revelation requires the world to be ready for him.***

**The Mashiach doesn't reveal himself until we've met our part of the prophecy as well.** It's a partnership rather than a one-sided affair. It is said that if the vast majority of the Jewish nation all repented for their sins overnight, the Mashiach would be revealed to us.

> R. Aha in the name of R. Tanhum b. R. Hiyya, **"If Israel repents for
>   one day, forthwith the son of David will come."** - The Jerusalem Talmud

**Judaism is a religion of process.** Things rarely occur within singular events and instead occur over a process over time.

- The world was created in 7 days
- The world was flooded for 40 days and nights
- Exodus occurred over a year with Ten Plagues **(Talmud - Ediyos 2:10)**
- The Jews wandered the desert for 40 years before we were ready

There is a very clear theme that runs through the Torah and this theme is things don't occur within an instant. Process is a function of divinity and things don't necessarily happen overnight and in singular events.

**The problem with your question is you're thinking of the Messianic Age as a thing which occurs overnight or in an instant. In reality, we're discussing something that is a process which occurs over decades or even centuries.**

- The Jewish refugees and Holocaust survivors who came to Israel after WW2 was one level of process.
- The Jews leaving the neighboring territories of the Middle East en mass was another level of the process.
- The continual arrival of Jews through Aliya is another level of process.

Again, the Torah shows us that things rarely occur in singular events but are processes that occur over time. To believe that because most of the Jews left the nations you cited is evidence that the prophecy can't be fulfilled is simply ignoring what is occurring as we speak.

**A good analogy for the Messianic Age is to think of it as a pregnancy.**

The average pregnancy takes nine months to complete and as the pregnancy draws closer, the mother experiences further discomfort and the tremblings (contractions) of a coming birth.

We're currently experiencing the contractions of the Messianic Age. The fact that birthing this new world can take some time, that doesn't mean it isn't happening. We need to be patient and accept that the process is moving forward at a natural pace.

Comment: Please back up your claim that we are currently in a “Messianic Age” from the Bible or established rabbinic tradition. There is absolutely no biblical proof or rabbinic proof for your statement, you are simply creating your own religious concept out of nothing that contradicts the Bible and the Rabbis. 
Personal inspirations don’t count especially if they contradict an explicit prophesy from God himself. 
Even many well known rabbis of the past believed that the Messiah will return the remnant such as Rambam. Unless you are willing to go against their word.

Comment: When God ordains something it happens according to the order that he commanded. So when you give the list of all the religious events that God ordained such as when commanded the sun and moon to be created in the fourth day, land animals didn't show up instead and then on the sixth day was the sun and moon created , when God made a plague the first plague of blood to happen, the plague of locusts didn't show up instead.

Comment: How is that supposed to be any different than the prophesy in Isaiah 11 that must go along the chronological order that God ordained in previous commands of a real and individual Messiah that will come first who will be righteous and just in all his ways, then a time of peace and utopianism will happen, then in that day(which is the day of peace and utopia) that the nations will seek him , that in that day(which is the day the nations will seek him ) God will return the remnant of those lands that I mentioned. These last two specifically follow the one before.

Comment: @user17175"...especially if they contradict an explicit prophesy from God himself. "

I'm afraid that I'll need to be the one asking you for such a citation. You're stating that Hashem gave us a specific timetable of events for the Mashiach and a specific order within which all prophecies are supposed to occur. 

I can assure you that no such document exists in Torah. The prophecies are varied and they never claim to be in a specific order. How they come is how they come. It was never broken down in (this is first, this is second, this is third, etc.)

So again, please cite such a quote.